# Never exits the trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am creating a v5 strategy. The first entry it makes on the lookback period is short, so I will use that. It enters the trade exactly correct, but never exits. There are 2 conditions that can cause an exit, 1 is that an indicator changes to a particular threshold, the other is ANY bullish candle. on the 1 trade entered in the lookback period, it enters the trade exactly at the right time, but never exits, and it should with the very next bullish candle. What am I doing wrong?

```
//create short condition
shortCondition = //logic here

//enter short trade
if strategy.position_size == 0 and shortCondition and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

//create var to make short exit condition
var bool shortExitCondition = false

//set short exit to true if green candle or other condition happens
if strategy.position_size != 0 and //other condition happens
    shortExitCondition := true
if strategy.position_size != 0 and open < close
    shortExitCondition := true

//close trade, reset short exit condition to false
if strategy.position_size != 0 and shortExitCondition and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.close("Close Short")
    shortExitCondition := false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `strategy.close()` is `id`.

> ***id (series string)*** A required parameter. The order identifier. It is
> possible to close an order by referencing its identifier.

You are passing "Close Short" as `id`, which means you want to close an order with the id "Close Short". However, your entry id is "Short".

Make it:

```
strategy.close("Short")
```

and it will be good.